# MVVM uwp UserControl with VM as DataTemplate

Tags: c#, mvvm, user-controls, uwp

I'm trying to create an app in UWP using MVVM pattern. 
It's possible that usercontrol which is a DataTemplate for items in Listbox would have his own VM.

Here is part of MainPage.xaml

```
 <ListBox Name="ListBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding Components}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate >
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="vm:ComponentUserControlViewModel"  >
                    <local:ComponentUserControl />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>
```

MainPageVM contains:

```
public ObservableCollection<Component> Components
```

For now it's my UserControl

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Id}" Grid.Row="0"></TextBox>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" Grid.Row="1"></TextBox>

</Grid>
```

VM:

```
    public class ComponentUserControlViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _componentId;
    private string _componentName;

    public ComponentUserControlViewModel()
    {
    }

    public string Id
    {
        get { return _componentId; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _componentId, value);
        }
    }
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _componentName; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _componentName, value);
        }
    }
```

What I want is for e.g. If I change `Id` property in my UI the view model `Id` property will changed too.

Comment: Your ComponentUserControl needs a (dependency) property, so that you can do `<local:ComponentUserControl Component="{Binding}" />`

Comment: Could u be more specific. I added this prop but how i should use it. I have no idea how it should work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What Kris stated is true, you need dependency properties to achieve what you want.

In short, you can have two types of properties: the good old properties like you have in your ViewModel, Id and Name, and dependency properties. (Of course there are attached properties too, but conceptually they are the same as dependency properties.) The main difference between these two types of properties is that while both types can be *targets* to a data binding, only dependency properties can be the *source* of a data binding. That's right what you need.

So to solve your problem, we'll need a dependency property, defined in the code-behind of your control. Let's call this property 'Component', like Kris does it in his answer:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ComponentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Component",
    typeof(ComponentUserControlViewModel), 
    typeof(ComponentUserControl), 
    new PropertyMetadata(null));
    
public ComponentUserControlViewModel Component
{
    get { return (ComponentUserControlViewModel) GetValue(ComponentProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ComponentProperty, value); }
}
```

Now if you change your binding on your UserControl to these (Note the Mode=OneWay, x:Bind is OneTime by default! More about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt204783.aspx).):

```
<TextBox Text="{x:Bind Component.Id, Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Row="0" />
<TextBox Text="{x:Bind Component.Name, Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Row="1" />
```

And replace your DataTemplate-s content with the one Kris supplied:

```
<local:ComponentUserControl Component="{Binding}" />
```

The magic will happen and all of this will work! :)
If you have any more questions on the matter, please check [this official overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt185583.aspx) of dependency properties.

Comment: My item source was type Component not ComponentViewModel...I had also a few logic mistakes in my thought,  thanks to your answer finally i did it.  I have also one more question, how  this Component="{Binding}" without anything after "Binding" bind the datacontext

Comment: Binding takes DataContext as the point to begin if you don't tell it to do it in another way explicitly. So when you are writing for example {Binding Id} it binds to the Id property of the DataContext of the control. In this case, ListView sets the DataContext of every item it creates based on your DataTemplate, so every ComponentUserControl's DataContext is a Component (ComponentViewModel in my answer) in this case. To bind the dependency property to it, you simply bind to the DataContext which is equal to writing {Binding}. Hope this helps!